# squid proxy acl for different ports

Tags: squid

I have squid proxy, which is currently allowing all vpc cidr range to whitelist file. I want to set-up an acl that the proxy client accessed on port 3128 it needs to apply whitelist1 and on port 3129 whitelist2. Is this possible ?

Comment: How did you go with this? I'm interested in setting this up too. Perhaps this answer's solution is applicable with dome editing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45966359

Answer (score 0):

OK got it working on my end. I'm using port 3128 as the normal proxy, and port 3127 as the alternate proxy (you may wish to change it to 3129). We are using it to restrict web access in exams hence the names of the ACLs below:

**/etc/squid/squid.conf**

#Normal Exam Proxy

```
acl exam dstdomain "/etc/squid/exam_allow.list"
acl examport localport 3128
http_access allow exam examport
```

#Alternate Exam Proxy

```
acl examalt dstdomain "/etc/squid/exam_allow_alt.list"
acl examaltport localport 3127
http_access allow examalt examaltport

http_port 3128
http_port 3127
```

**Optional - firewall: allow port 3127**

If you have firewalld on your server you may want to allow the new port through ;-)

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=3127/tcp

firewall-cmd --reload
```

**Optional - Chrome Browser Managed Policy**

We force Google Chrome browser to use the proxy using a managed policy. On Linux desktop this looks like the following:

File: /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/managed_policies.json

```
{
  "HomepageLocation": "about:blank",
  "HomepageIsNewTabPage": false,
  "DefaultBrowserSettingEnabled": true,
  "RestoreOnStartup": 1,
  "SafeBrowsingProtectionLevel": 1,
  "ProxySettings": {
    "ProxyBypassList": "*url1.com,*url2.com",
    "ProxyMode": "fixed_servers",
    "ProxyServer": "proxyserver_ip:3127"
  }
}
```